# Initialize the map with new (), and then assign a key to the panic exception, why?

Tags: dictionary, pointers, go

My go version is `go1.13.6`

Run this code:

```
func main() {
  s := new(map[int]int)
  (*s)[1] = 4
  println((*s)[1])
}
```

Console says:

```
panic: assignment to entry in nil map
```

So, I try this:

```
func main() {
  s := new(map[int]int)
  println(s == nil)
}
```

Console shows `false`

Then I try this:

```
func main() {
  s := new(map[int]int)
  *s = map[int]int{}
  (*s)[1] = 4
  println((*s)[1])
}
```

Console shows `4`

Answer (score 0):

[`new`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new) just allocates memory and zeros it, and the zeroed map is not ready for use.

> The built-in function make(T, args) serves a purpose different from new(T). It creates slices, maps, and channels only, and it returns an initialized (not zeroed) value of type T (not *T). The reason for the distinction is that these three types represent, under the covers, references to data structures that must be initialized before use. A slice, for example, is a three-item descriptor containing a pointer to the data (inside an array), the length, and the capacity, and until those items are initialized, the slice is nil. For slices, maps, and channels, make initializes the internal data structure and prepares the value for use.

You should use [`make`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_make) instead.